# installing and using curl commands on an esp32

Tags: c++, http, curl, post

I have been trying to understand and install curl on visual studio code so I can use curl commands with my esp32. However I just can't get it to work, everything is very daunting to me and I understand very little of what tutorials offer me. Most of them operate with Linux and enter weird commands. I work on windows and I have absolutely no idea how to use all of those weird command lines. I am trying to make an Http Post request to a web server. Could someone help me setup curl so I can make a simple Http Post request and send a single JSON string in visual studio code? After all this information bombed on me in the last hour, I just can't see any logic. So after a few days, I finally resorted to asking on here. In advance: Thank you so much for your help.

Thomas

Comment: If you want use only one simple POST you can enter in your PowerShell (you already have it installed on Windows) and type curl, it is not curl actualy but it is an alternative that doesn't need instalation

Answer (score 0):

Try this vs code extension
mkloubert.vscode-http-client
accessible here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vscode-http-client

Or the postman desktop app

Comment: To make the answer more complete, I suggest adding links to the suggested extensions and apps.